# how to make 4 subtables in one row latex

Tags: tables

I wanted to place tables horizontally side by side, so i used subtable to create (3 x 2) structure in this way (this is how one of my pages looks like):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Caption}
\centering

\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=100$ \label{tab:tab_1}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=200$ \label{tab:tab_2}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=300$ \label{tab:tab_3}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=400$\label{tab:tab_4}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=500$ \label{tab:tab_5}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}%
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$n=600$\label{tab:tab_6}}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\hline
\input{tab_all/tab_1.tex}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\end{table}

\pagebreak
.... same stucture on the next page
```

I have these on two pages, so 3 more tables (with 2 subtables each) on next page, which i separated with `\pagebreak`. I have two questions:

1. How can i fix the problem of "stretching" tables, i.e. these three rows on each page stretch so that it is evenly distributed over one page which i do not want...
2. How could i put my two pages on one (side by side), i.e, how could i get 4 subtables in one row, with subtitle for each pair?

For example purposes, i input here all the time same tab_1, because all tables are in fact same size, just numbers change... Here is the content of the separate tab_1.tex file which i input(table is small so it is no problem to fit 4 in one row in terms of space..)

```
& param & error \cr\hline
$\beta$   &   0.005   &   5.1e-04   \cr  
$\gamma_1$   &   -0.116   &   0.014   \cr  
$\omega$   &   1.083   &   1.172   \cr  
$\delta$   &   -0.265   &   0.071   \cr  
\hline
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am not sure how to simplify it since the issue is in adding many tables into one page... i changed codes, since all subtables are same shape and size i gave codes for one from separated .tex file from which i input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have several tables in a row you only need join all the `tabular` environments, without blank lines between. To obtain equal spaces between the tables, use `\hfill`.

> [image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[a3paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}
\parskip2em\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\bgroup\Large
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
    11 & 12 & 13\\\midrule
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
    11 & 12 & 13\\\midrule
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
    11 & 12 & 13\\\midrule
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill
\begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
    11 & 12 & 13\\\midrule
    21 & 22 & 23\\
    31 & 32 & 33\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\hfill\mbox{}
\egroup

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Im an not sure if you want also equal spaces for tables of diferent columns/sizes (i.e, each table plus padding take always 1/4 of the text width). In that case, one option is use the `tabularx` package for the main (hide) table or enclose each table in a `minipage` of `.25\textwidth`.